# Why does this code write out TWO documents?

Tags: xpages

Have a database where I only want one document for a certain category. So when the user goes to this Xpage I want to test to see if there is already a doc, and if so grab that one, if not, then create and save one.

I wrote some SSJS in the datasource to do this, but the first time I run it it creates two docs. I put a print in the code and it executes this part twice. Why does it do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedPage = "page001"}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/xpValidationDocument.jss" clientSide="false" />
        <xp:styleSheet href="/custom.css" />
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" action="editDocument">
            <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedPage = "page001";
var v:NotesView = database.getView(sessionScope.selectedPage)
var doc:NotesDocuent = v.getFirstDocument()
if (doc == null)
{doc = database.createDocument();
doc.appendItemValue("form","document");
doc.appendItemValue("key",sessionScope.selectedPage);
doc.appendItemValue("crtUsr",session.getCommonUserName());
doc.appendItemValue("crtDte",session.evaluate('@Today'))
doc.save();
print ("here");
return doc.getUniversalID();}
else
{
print ("here2");
return doc.getUniversalID()}}]]></xp:this.documentId>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:panel style="width:900.00px" id="pnlForm">
        <xe:widgetContainer id="widgetContainerHeader"
            style="width:100%">

            <xp:panel id="plContainer">
                <xe:formTable id="frLocationMaster"
                    disableErrorSummary="true" disableRowError="true"
                    style="lotusForm2" styleClass="scllotusui30dojo">
                    <xp:this.facets />

                    <xe:formRow id="formRow5" labelPosition="none"
                        style="padding-bottom:10.0px">
                        <xp:table style="width:99%" border="0"
                            cellpadding="0" role="presentation" cellspacing="0"
                            id="table2">
                            <xp:tr>
                                <xp:td
                                    style="width:80.00px;min-width:120px">
                                    <xp:label id="label2" for="formRow1"
                                        value="Notes" />
                                </xp:td>
                                <xp:td style="width:px">
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichText1" value="#{document1.Body}">
                                        <xp:this.attrs>
                                            <xp:attr name="toolbar">
                                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
            [
                ["Format", "Font", "FontSize"],
                ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "-", "TextColor", "BGColor", "-", "JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock", "NumberedList", "-", "BulletedList"],
                ["Indent", "Outdent"],
                ["Subscript", "Superscript"],
                ["RemoveFormat", "-", "MenuPaste", "-", "Undo", "Redo", "Find", "LotusSpellChecker", "-", "Image", "Table", "Link", "Flash", "-", "PageBreak", "HorizontalRule", "SpecialChar", "Blockquote", "Smiley", "ShowBlocks"],
                ["Maximize", "Source"]
            ]
        ]]></xp:this.value>
                                            </xp:attr>
                                        </xp:this.attrs>
                                        <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                                            <xp:dojoAttribute
                                                name="enterMode" value="2" />
                                        </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:td>
                            </xp:tr>
                        </xp:table>
                    </xe:formRow>

                </xe:formTable>
            </xp:panel>
        </xe:widgetContainer>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Because of the request processing life cycle. Try making the documentId property computed on load by replacing # with $.

Answer (score 0):

After you have created the document det the UNID or the NoteID in a viewScope variable and at the top of you code check if the scope variable is null if not use that one.
the reason for this is that the datasource is recalculated several times while loading the page.

So the code would be something like this

```
sessionScope.selectedPage = "page001";
if(viewScope.thisUNID==null){
var v:NotesView = database.getView(sessionScope.selectedPage)
var doc:NotesDocuent = v.getFirstDocument()
if (doc == null)
{doc = database.createDocument();
doc.appendItemValue("form","document");
doc.appendItemValue("key",sessionScope.selectedPage);
doc.appendItemValue("crtUsr",session.getCommonUserName());
doc.appendItemValue("crtDte",session.evaluate('@Today'))
doc.save();
print ("here");
viewScope.thisUNID=doc.getUniversalID()
return viewScope.thisUNID;}
else
{
print ("here2");
viewScope.thisUNID=doc.getUniversalID()
return viewScope.thisUNID}
}else{
return viewScope.ThisUNID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems on a quick review.

As Per says, documentId may need to be page load binding, not runtime - the datasource had to be loaded in before render response, and runtime binding may not run early enough.

But the bigger problem is your documentId code is not going to have any effect, because you are not setting `ignoreRequestParams="true"`. Consequently the documentId will be picked up from the URL parameters and, if there's nothing there, it will create a new document each time.

Comment: Paul, that is very interesting, as I made the change Per suggested and it solved the two doc problem, but then I was getting save/reps every time after the first save. Came back and saw your post, and made the change to ignoreRequestParams="true" and that fixed the rep/save conflict.